# What are some helpful blogs for memoir writing?

Tags: resources, blog

I am interested in finding more online resources for memoir writing. Any ideas?

Comment: What kind of resources? Examples of memoirs? Advice on structure? Applications that will help you organize your memoir? Blogs where people talk about their memoirs or publish them in a blog, perhaps?

Comment: No, first time on site. I'm looking for a site where perhaps there are prompts given and people that write a memoir. Is that realistic? I used to be on a site called memoir cafe which is now defunct.

Comment: I am interested in a variety of resources related to memoir writing. All of the ideas you listed could be useful. I am more interested in the blogs focused on helping a person write, structure, revise, and publish a memoir.

Answer (score 3):

I took the liberty of bing'ing "How to write a memoir" and read through some of the better links (I skipped the ehow.com stuff).

[This article](http://www.theamericanscholar.org/how-to-write-a-memoir/) by William Zinsser was my favorite. It's not a blog, but has what looks like some good tips.

I also liked [this one](http://www.rd.com/your-america-inspiring-people-and-stories/great-tips-on-how-to-write-your-memoir/article112510.html) - specifically for the tips on the second page.

Disclaimer: I haven't written my memoir, and don't know if I ever will. Someone who's done this sort of thing is likely to have much better advice. In the meantime, I hope you find these useful.